# Using custom layer and py_function with opencv method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My development environment is

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.8
- Tensorflow 1.13.1

My goal is to implement a layer that can transform each cnn filter to hu moments invariants ( each filter -> 7 dimensions value)

So that, I want to use Opencv's Humoment method

Here is my Layer defined:

```
class MomentLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MomentLayer, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.oshape = input_shape
        super(MomentLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        xout = tf.py_function(image_tensor_func, (inputs,), 'float32', name='Cvopt')
        xout.set_shape(tf.TensorShape((None, self.oshape[-1] * 7)))
        return xout

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return tf.TensorShape((None, input_shape[-1] * 7))
```

and my py_function is

```
def image_tensor_func(img4d):
    img4dx = tf.transpose(img4d, [0, 3, 1, 2])
    all_data = np.array([])
    for img3dx in img4dx:
        tmp = np.array([])
        for efilter in img3dx:
            hu = cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(efilter.numpy())).flatten()
            if tmp.shape[0] == 0:
                tmp = hu
            else:
                tmp = np.concatenate((tmp, hu), axis=None)
        if all_data.shape[0] == 0:
            all_data = tmp
        else:
            all_data = np.vstack((all_data, tmp))

    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(all_data, dtype=tf.float32)
    return x
```

Finally, I define the network

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10, 10, 1))
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=5, activation=tf.nn.relu)(input)
test_layer = MomentLayer()(conv1)
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=12, activation=tf.nn.relu)(test_layer)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(dense1)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.01),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy])
print(model.summary())
```

and model.summary() is work fine!

but when I try to feed data

I got error

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: transpose expects a vector of size 0. But input(1) is a vector of size 4
>        [[{{node training/TFOptimizer/gradients/Relu_grad/ReluGrad-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]] [Op:StatefulPartitionedCall]

I'm pretty sure that the shape of data is right.

I wonder that the tensorflow can not write code like this.

Comment: I have a same problem with writint custom layer with tf.py_function too, Does you solved your problem? if you do so, how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You input data consists of features and labels. Therefore you would need to make sure the shape of labels is also correct.